# add crossorigin attribute to script tag with require js

Tags: javascript, requirejs

here my problem,
I call a lot of script with requirejs and for one of them (and ONLY one) I need to add crossorigin attribute to make my script call look like that

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" async 
data-requirecontext="_" data-requiremodule="myModule" 
src="cdn.moduleUrl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

I've already search on docs, google and stackOverflow but I could'n find any response.

P.S.: I use requirejs 2.3.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so I finnaly found a "proper" solution to my problem, in require code, you have an **undocumented option** `onNodeCreated` to set a callback before inserting script tag on dom so with this code, I achieve my goal !

```
require.config({
  paths: {
    'myModule': 'cdn.moduleUrl'
  },
  attributes: {
    "myModule": {
      crossorigin: "anonymous"
    }
  }, 
  onNodeCreated: function(node, config, name, url){
    if(config.attributes && config.attributes[name]){
      Object.keys(config.attributes[name]).forEach(attribute => {
        node.setAttribute(attribute, config.attributes[name][attribute]);
      });
    }
  }
});
```